# Status bar notification android using HTML5 audio

Tags: android, html, audio, notifications, native

How can I add an android notification when an audio is playing on my website like for example soundcloud is doing ?

Is that HTML5 Notifications API ?

See images below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/45jcusntuaix3yw/Screenshot_2015-10-01-20-12-13.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eft9sj4pdy6jn23/Screenshot_2015-10-01-20-13-33.png?dl=0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it I guess. You have to use the new Web Audio API instead of HTML5 audio.

Thanks anyway.